# Why can't class methods call other class methods or themselves?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I am curious why methods cannot call other methods or themselves in javascript. For example, this produces a Reference error saying add is not defined.

```
class sum {
  add(x, amt) {
    if(amt == 0) return x
    return add(x+1, amt-1)
  }
}
summer = new sum()
console.log(summer.add(5,5))
```

You must use this.add() instead.

Now I understand that the methods get translated to functions on the prototype but I don't see how that explains this limitation I'm pointing out?

Couldn't one reason that when add is defined it could have references to itself or other methods with a closure capture.

Why is it this way?

Comment: You must be from Java.... (also, `add` is not a class method, it's an instance method)

Comment: what if you have a global `add` function that returns `a-b` and want to use it instead? https://jsfiddle.net/gh97ynt3/ It's in this way because that's how `global` variable works in javascript.

Comment: @briosheje Okay, but! Why does it have to be ambiguous? Why can't you say that the class {} braces are the inner most scope and thus should select that add instead of the global add?

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined, period. The rules are different than in other languages.

Comment: What about object methods? `{ foo() { bar() }, bar() {} }` ? If the powers that be decided to follow your rules, they'd either have to make object methods work the same as class methods (for consistency) but then scoping rules in object methods and object function properties (`{foo: function() {}}`) would be inconsistent, or they would leave objects alone and have inconsistency between object and class methods. By making methods (mostly) work like any other function, they avoid that confusion.

Comment: Very generally speaking, there are few "hard" reasons why something has to be done a certain way. Most design decisions are trade offs and anything can factor into that decision (ease of implementation, design consistency, principle of least surprise, historic context, precedence in other languages, backwards compatibility, etc).

Comment: @FelixKling that's a good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to make it "slightly" more theorical, without going too deep in the documentations and so on.

The main answer to your question can be found by transpiling your code to plain javascript. To accomplish that, you can either use babel online or the typescript online playground.
Either case, the transpiled code will look like this:

```
"use strict";
var sum = /** @class */ (function () {
    function sum() {
    }
    sum.prototype.add = function (x, amt) {
        if (amt == 0)
            return x;
        return add(x + 1, amt - 1);
    };
    return sum;
}());
var summer = new sum();
console.log(summer.add(5, 5));
```

As you can see, the `add` method belongs to the **sum** prototype, which is a **function**. Therefore, you can guess that accessing `add` whithin the `add` scope just **can't** implicitly lead to invoking the `sum.prototype.add` function.

Differently, if you look at the **correct** code:

```
class sum {
  add(x, amt) {
    if(amt == 0) return x
    return this.add(x+1, amt-1)
  }
}
var summer = new sum()
console.log(summer.add(5,5))
```

You will see that the transpiled code will invoke the `this` method:

```
"use strict";
var sum = /** @class */ (function () {
    function sum() {
    }
    sum.prototype.add = function (x, amt) {
        if (amt == 0)
            return x;
        return this.add(x + 1, amt - 1);
    };
    return sum;
}());
var summer = new sum();
console.log(summer.add(5, 5));
```

This is not really matter of being **ambiguous**, it's rather that, in javascript, such kind of invocation is allowed, because the `add` method is implicitly available from the global scope. Being able to access the global scope in your function scope (because remember that, whatever happens, a `class` in javascript is **always** transpiled to a function) allows to inherit the standard behavior of a function, which is having access to its parent, having its own scope and granting access to the global scope.

A little curiosity: if you actually could access `this.add` using `add`, you wouldn't be able to use `undefined`, since it's a **global variable**, hence you wouldn't be able to access it and use it, because it would implicitly be `this.undefined`.

So, once again, it's **not** about ambiguity, it's about how javascript **functions** works.

Comment: If you declare the function in the scope before assigning it to the prototype in that transpiled code, you can take advantage of function hoisting. Then the "methods" can reference each other : https://pastebin.com/2nqipgMP

Comment: @Thomas indeed you can do that, though it involves working in the transpiled code in plain javascript. As a side note, you should be careful about the so called "shadowing". If you have a global add function, that will be shadowed by the inner one, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8gfxpyLj/ The whole point is that the kind of `OOP` available in javascript is slightly different from some other ones due to how the language is designed.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the middle of illustrating this shortcoming when [@briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275797/briosheje) made the comment:

```js
function add() {
   console.log('called the wrong add!');
}

class sum {
  add(x, amt) {
    if(amt == 0) return x
    return add(x+1, amt-1)
  }
}
summer = new sum()
console.log(summer.add(5,5))
```

Comment: (As a side note, `add` could be literally **anything**, not just a function)

Comment: @Adam Okay, but! Why does it have to be ambiguous? Why can't you say that the class {} braces are the inner most scope and thus it should select that add method instead of the global add?

Comment: To play devil's advocate, this in itself isn't really an argument. There could be disambiguation rules to access the outer `add` even when it's shadowed (e.g. `\add()` or something)…

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally OOP in Javascript is very different to [java](/questions/tagged/java) and other languages. There's not actually a strong concept of "classes". The classic OOP concepts like classes and instances in Javascript don't really come from "classes", but from the rules surrounding property lookups and the `this` and `new` keywords. Everything else is just functions, objects and properties—some of which are "special", like `prototype`.

E.g. you can assemble a "class" like this:

```js
function Foo() {
    this.bar = 42;
}

function baz() {
    return this.bar;
}

Foo.prototype.baz = baz;

let foo = new Foo;
console.log(foo.baz());
```

There's no real cohesion here, `baz` doesn't intrinsically belong to any class, yet assembled like this they act like one. And the `class` syntax is just a thin veneer over this mechanism. So, if you write `add` inside a *function*, it follows variable scoping rules and will look up a variable in some surrounding scope, it's not going to find a method on a prototype.